# Правила наименования меток

Tags: обсуждение, faq, метки, справка

Хочется собрать в одном месте рекомендации по правильному наименованию меток (к сожалению, в справке не нашёл этой информации).

1. Стоит ли называть метку просто [django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) или же [python-django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-django), так как их всё равно ставят вместе и эти две метки неразделимы

   - В случае, если не добавлять префикс `python-` к метке, нужно ли в вопросе про django **всегда** указывать обе метки [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django)? Ведь если не указывать, то по метке [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) не будут доступны вопросы про django.
2. Также какие рекомендации по поводу того, каким образом разбиваются слова в названии меток: [beautiful-soup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautiful-soup) или [beautifulsoup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup)?
3. Следует ли к названию библиотеки, которая существует только для одного языка, добавлять приставкой этот язык (например, [python-beautifulsoup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-beautifulsoup))?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Префиксы и суффиксы добавляют, когда нужно нужно разрешить [**неоднозначность**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation), например:

- [stash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stash) > [git-stash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-stash) + [atlassian-stash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-stash)
- [poisson](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poisson) > [poisson-distribution](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poisson-distribution) + [poisson-equation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poisson-equation)
- [react](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) > [reactjs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) + [reactphp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactphp)

Формирование названия тега в идеале должно происходить по простому алгоритму, чтобы можно было легко восставновить оригинальное написание: все пробелы заменить на дефисы, перевести в нижний регистр. Это означает, что если слова выделены только регистром, а не пробелами, то дефис не добавляется.

- Точки: Node.js > [node.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js), ASP.NET > [asp.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net), VB.NET > [vb.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net)
- Слитно: AngularJS > [angularjs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), JavaFX > [javafx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx), DataGridView > [datagridview](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datagridview), UITableView > [uitableview](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableview)
- Пробелы: Java EE > [java-ee](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee), Java EE 6 > [java-ee-6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee-6), Java Web Start > [java-web-start](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-web-start)
- Смесь: JavaFX 2 > [javafx-2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx-2), ASP.NET MVC 4 > [asp.net-mvc-4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4)

Иногда можно встретить альтернативное наименование, особенно у относительно редких тегов, но в целом система такая, вроде. Авторы называют библиотеку Beautiful Soup, поэтому правильно будет назвать тег [beautiful-soup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautiful-soup) (хотя на большом СО [beautifulsoup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup)...).

И конкретно по случаю Django: нужно поставить теги [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) и [django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django). Разработка на этом фреймворке возможна только с помощью Python, и подсветка кода будет корректно работать, только если поставить языковой тег, поэтому вопросов насчёт [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) не возникает. (Сложнее случаи, когда библиотека доступна на нескольких языках — это отдельный вопрос.) Так как Django только один (в программировании), то неоднозначностей нет, поэтому правильно использовать [django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django).

Comment: Со всем согласен, кроме слитного написания в случае неоднозначности. Как мне кажется, слитное написание не требуется, вместо этого следует использовать несколько меток. Например, вместо одной метки [tag:git-stash] лучше использовать две: [tag:git] и [tag:stash].

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я тоже не в восторге от слитного написания, просто выбрал первые попавшиеся примеры неоднозначностей. А вот тег stash — не самая лучшая идея, потому что stash — это не какое-то общее межъязыковое и межплатформенное понятие, а просто слово, которое в разных местах используется с совершенно разными значениями.

Answer (score 3):

Общее мета-замечание: [Pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) содержит мудрую цитату:

> A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds

Которая близка по смыслу русской пословице: "Научи дурака богу молиться—он себе лоб расшибёт".

То есть всегда нужно голову использовать, а не слепо подчиняться правилам. Если нарушение правила может улучшить результат в данном конкретном случае, то следует нарушить это правило в данном конкретном случае.

По поводу меток: вместо создания сложного свода правил, можно использовать метки с большого Stack Overflow в качестве первого приближения, a именно:

- `[python]`  `[django]`
- `[python]`  `[beautifulsoup]`
- `[python]`  `[python-requests]`

где вместо `python` можно использовать более специфичные версии `python-2.7` или `python-3.x`, если вопрос этого требует.

Для альтернативных вариантов можно создать синонимы, если необходимо, например,

- `python-django` -> `django`
- `python-beautifulsoup` -> `beautifulsoup`
- `beautiful-soup` -> `beautifulsoup`

В последнем случае, не ясно почему движок автоматически не игнорирует разницу, если отличие только в дефисе, по-видимому стандартного процесса голосования по синонимам достаточно.

Answer (score 2):

1. [django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) Также как и [jquery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) - это javascript, а [boost](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost) - это c++.
2. [beautiful-soup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautiful-soup) смотрится лучше, в отсутствие CamelCase, иначе был бы BeautifulSoup...
3. см. 1.
4. Для версий стоит также использовать `-`, например [delphi-7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-7)[delphi-xe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-xe)...