# Переименование меток про Python

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, переименование-метки

Предлагаю переименовать метку [python2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python2) в [python-2.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) и, соответственно, [python3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python3) в [python-3.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x). Так они смотрятся понятнее и сочетаются с конкретными версионными метками типа [python-2.6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.6) и [python-3.2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Полностью поддерживаю.

Предлагаю такой стиль наименования сделать стандартом для всех объектов, где есть минорные версии, то есть `name-5.0`, `name-5.1`, `name-5.2` >> [name-5.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/name-5.x)  Практически всегда первого числа достаточно.

Почему не просто [name-5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/name-5)? Потому что вариант [name-5.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/name-5.x) **явным** образом указывает, что он подходит для 5.1 и для 5.7. А вариант [name-5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/name-5) делает это **неявным** образом и пользователь может подумать, что ему это не подходит.

Исключение: когда `name-5.x` и `name-5.y` существенно, несовместимо отличаются друг от друга. Например, .Net 3.0 и .Net 3.5.

Достаточно хорошо об этом написано в конце этого вопроса: [Версии в названиях меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325/)

После обсуждения нужно внести дополнение в [Правила наименования меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251/)