# Версии в названиях меток

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, переименование-метки

Переименовать (метки в порядке популярности):

- [windows7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows7) > [windows-7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-7)
- [as3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/as3) > [actionscript-3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-3)
- [windowsphone8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsphone8) > [windows-phone-8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8)
- [windowsphone7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsphone7) > [windows-phone-7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7)
- [windows8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows8) > [windows-8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-8)
- [error-404](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error-404) > [http-status-code-404](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-404)
- [css2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2) > [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) *(в объективной реальности CSS1 не используется)*
- [win32](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win32) > [winapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi)
- [vb6.0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6.0) > [vb6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6)
- [wp7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wp7) > [windows-phone-7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7)
- [windows2008r2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows2008r2) > [windows-server-2008-r2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008-r2)
- [google-maps-api-v2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-v2) > [google-maps-api-2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2)
- [actionscript3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript3) > [actionscript-3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-3)
- [.net4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net4) > [.net-4.0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.0)
- [kohana3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kohana3) > [kohana-3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kohana-3)
- [zend](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend) > [zend-framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework)
- [zend2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend2) > [zend-framework-2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework-2)
- [zf2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zf2) > [zend-framework-2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework-2)
- [apache22](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache22) > [apache2.2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache2.2)
- [windows2008](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows2008) > [windows-server-2008](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008)
- [xna4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xna4) > [xna-4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xna-4)
- [wp8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wp8) > [windows-phone-8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8)
- [utf8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/utf8) > [utf-8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/utf-8)
- [.net4.5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net4.5) > [.net-4.5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.5)
- [404](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/404) > [http-status-code-404](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-404)
- [win-1251](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-1251) > [cp1251](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp1251)
- [iis7.0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iis7.0) > [iis-7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iis-7)
- [2008r2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2008r2) > [windows-server-2008-r2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008-r2)

Общая идея: если есть [сущность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c), то вторая версия сущности будет [сущность-2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-2). Если традиционно цифра пишется слитно, то [сущность2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c2). Если популярны сущности с минорными версиями, то [сущность-2.0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-2.0) и [сущность-2.5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-2.5) (или [сущность2.0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c2.0) и [сущность2.5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c2.5), если слитно). Сокращения недопустимы, везде используется официальное название.

В качестве ориентира использовался большой Stack Overflow.

Запрос на Data.SE, использованный в качестве источника: [Tags with version numbers](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/312676/tags-with-version-numbers).