# Объединения меток для Windows

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, переименование-метки

На мой взгляд в метках `windows*` у нас творится чёрт знает что. Предлагаю привести все метки для Windows к следующему виду: `windows-*`. Таким образом требуются следующее переименования(создания синонимов?):

[windows7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows7) -> [windows-7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-7)

[windowsphone8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsphone8) -> [windows-phone-8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8)

[windows8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows8) -> [windows-8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-8)

[windowsphone7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsphone7) -> [windows-phone-7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7)

[windowsxp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsxp) -> [windows-xp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp)

[windows2008](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows2008) -> [windows-server-2008](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008)

[windows2008r2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows2008r2) -> [windows-server-2008-r2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008-r2)

[windows-phone](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone) -> [windows-phone](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone)

[windowsce](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsce) -> [windows-ce](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-ce)

[windowsserver](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsserver) -> [windows-server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server)

Answer (score 2):

Половина этих меток разобрана в моём вопросе [Версии в названиях меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325/) (а именно все метки с цифрами). Только *некоторые модераторы* этот вопрос игнорируют.

Из отличий: метка должна быть [windows-server-2008](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008), а не [windows-2008](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-2008), то же с R2 — чтобы было как на большом СО. В остальном согласен.

Comment: Поправил, спасибо!