# Объединения меток для OS X

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть несколько меток, которые подразумевают OS X: [mac-os-x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-x), [os-x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x), [macos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos).
Их все нужно сделать синонимом к метке [osx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx), т.к. именно эта метка отражает название ОС и позволят в дальнейшем создавать метки специфичные к её версии. Например [osx-lion](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-lion)

Comment: Под macos может быть имеется в виду [классическая MacOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS#.22Classic.22_Mac_OS_.281984.E2.80.932001.29)?

Comment: @VladD, я думаю, что про классику мало кто знает. И вопросы по ней слишком маловероятны, т.к. её уже давно нет. Ещё по 10.6 вероятны вопросы(но это OS X), а более ранние, если только в музее.

Comment: Может быть, тогда выпилить `macos` вообще, для исключения разночтений, и сделать `macos-classic`? Или проблема несущественна?

Comment: @VladD Если вы сможете найти хотя бы один вопрос по классике, то можно сделать и [tag:macos-classic], конечно. Но вы такой вопрос сначала найдите. :)

Comment: @VladD, можно и выпилить, но есть много людей, кто называет os x - macos. Просто по привычке или по незнанию и велика вероятность, что его опять создадут. Поэтому я выступаю за синоним.

Comment: Поддерживаю синоним. Я тоже использую OS X и называю ее макосью. Главным OS X, остальное в синонимы.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно принятому порядку ([Правила наименования меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251/181472), см. пункт 2) пробел в названии метки должен заменяться на `-`:

[os-x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x)

Производные будут выглядеть так:

[os-x-yosemite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x-yosemite)

Нельзя ли изменить центральную метку? (Например, переименовать).

Comment: Будет неконсистентно с SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx

Comment: @Nofate ну и что? :)

Comment: Не смотрятся же производные с дефисом...